# How to set a smooth scrolling to my JS navigation bar?

Tags: javascript

I have coded a nav bar using JS, I need to add a smooth scroll active when a user clicks on one of the section written in pure JS (and not CSS's smooth scrolling)
I was thinking something with scrollIntoView or scrollTo but each time I code it it either makes the navbar disappear or not work at all.
Here's my navbar code. Any help is appreciaited.

```
function navBar() {
    const section = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

    for (let i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
      let navBarUL = document.getElementById("navBarULID");
      let link = `<a href='#' onclick="console.log(${i})" id='link_no${i+1}'> Section ${i+1} </a>`;

      
      let newLI = document.createElement("li")
      newLI.innerHTML = link
      navBarUL.appendChild(newLI)
      let j = i
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById( 'link_no' + (i + 1)).addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      
        e.preventDefault();


        let allActiveLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('active-link');
        for (let i = 0; i < allActiveLinks.length; i++) {
            const element = allActiveLinks[i];
            element.classList.remove('active-link');
            
        }
```

Here's an HTML sample

```
<ul id="navBarULID"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1 id="p1">Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <section  id="section1"  class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2 id="section1ID">Section 1</h2>
        <p>test.</p>

       
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" >
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2 id="section2ID">Section 2</h2>
        <p>test.</p>

        
      </div>
    </section>
<section id="section3" >
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2 id="section3ID">Section 3</h2>
        <p>test.</p>

     
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS code

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

Comment: I am required to use pure JS and not CSS sadly.